# Python asyncio - Increase the value of Semaphore

Tags: python-asyncio

I am making use of `aiohttp` in one of my projects and would like to limit the number of requests made per second. I am using `asyncio.Semaphore` to do that. My challenge is I may want to increase/decrease the number of requests allowed per second.

For example:

```
limit = asyncio.Semaphore(10)
async with limit:
    async with aiohttp.request(...)
        ...
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

This works great. That is, it limits that `aiohttp.request` to 10 concurrent requests in a second. However, I may want to increase and decrease the `Semaphore._value`. I can do `limit._value = 20` but I am not sure if this is the right approach or there is another way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the private `_value` attribute is not the right approach for at least two reasons: one that the attribute is private and can be removed, renamed, or change meaning in a future version without notice, and the other that increasing the limit won't be noticed by a semaphore that already has waiters.

Since `asyncio.Semaphore` doesn't support modifying the limit dynamically, you have two options: implementing your own `Semaphore` class that does support it, or not using a `Semaphore` at all. The latter is probably easier as you can always replace a semaphore-enforced limit with a fixed number of worker tasks that receive jobs through a queue. Assuming you currently have code that looks like this:

```
async def fetch(limit, arg):
    async with limit:
        # your actual code here
        return result

async def tweak_limit(limit):
    # here you'd like to be able to increase the limit

async def main():
    limit = asyncio.Semaphore(10)
    asyncio.create_task(tweak_limit(limit))
    results = await asyncio.gather(*[fetch(limit, x) for x in range(1000)])
```

You could express it without a semaphore by creating workers in advance and giving them work to do:

```
async def fetch_task(queue, results):
    while True:
        arg = await queue.get()
        # your actual code here
        results.append(result)
        queue.task_done()

async def main():
    # fill the queue with jobs for the workers
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    for x in range(1000):
        await queue.put(x)

    # create the initial pool of workers
    results = []
    workers = [asyncio.create_task(fetch_task(queue, results))
               for _ in range(10)]
    asyncio.create_task(tweak_limit(workers, queue, results))

    # wait for workers to process the entire queue
    await queue.join()
    # finally, cancel the now-idle worker tasks
    for w in workers:
        w.cancel()

    # results are now available
```

The `tweak_limit()` function can now increase the limit simply by spawning new workers:

```
async def tweak_limit(workers, queue, results):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        if need_more_workers:
            workers.append(asyncio.create_task(fetch_task(queue, results)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using workers and queues is a more complex solution, you have to think about issues like setup, teardown, exception handling and backpressure, etc.

Semaphore can be implemented with Lock, if you don't mind abit of inefficiency (you will see why), here's a simple implemention for a dynamic-value semaphore:

```py
class DynamicSemaphore:
    def __init__(self, value=1):
        self._lock = asyncio.Lock()

        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Semaphore initial value must be >= 0")

        self.value = value

    async def __aenter__(self):
        await self.acquire()
        return None

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        self.release()

    def locked(self):
        return self.value == 0

    async def acquire(self):
        async with self._lock:
            while self.value <= 0:
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

        self.value -= 1
        return True

    def release(self):
        self.value += 1
```